# PHP - get beginning inventory from ending inventory of last month

Tags: php, sql

I have an orders table and inventory table. I need a function to get the beginning inventory of last month.

This is the formula.

beginning inventory = ending inventory

ending inventory = beginning inventory + deliveries - usage.

To get the ending inventory of last month, I  need to get the beginning inventory of last last month but I don't know how to do that.

I am just thinking on how to do it.

```
    <?php
     function get_beginning_inventory($month_date)
     {
       //do the formula here or the code here
       return $data;
     }
    ?>
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Such effort you've put up writing that code.

Comment: We would need to see the table schema and examples of its contents

Comment: If you can, I think you should research into double entry accounting and rethink your data models.
You would be able to present the accurate inventory for any point of time in a blink